# Shopping Cart with just Enquiry

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp, shopping-cart

I wanna build a Shopping Cart to submit enquiry about the products and to buy the product.
Each of the products will have varying levels of categories.

Examples
1. Brand > Product Line > Category 1 > Category 2 > Product
2. Brand > Product Line > Category 1 > Product
3. Brand > Product Line > Product

Now the user has to be able to add the products from various brands to a shopping cart and submit for price enquiry with their contact details.

Is there any Ready made CMS avaiable that i can use to get a shorter turn around time for such an application.

I would love to use wordpress or cakephp to build the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use wordpress and install the e [commerce plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce). Or use a theme like [shopperpress](http://www.shopperpress.com).

Comment: how easy is it to theme ?

Comment: Very easy, tutorials are available.